# Every/All person/people 's time

Tags: time, saxon-genitive

We have 10 people.
We assign a time interval to each one. For example, they could live 1 year, 2 years,... 10 years.
And I want to calculate the sum of all their times.

What's the proper way to tell it?

I want to add...

- every people's time.
- every person's time.
- all people's time.
- all person's time.

or maybe better without the Saxon genitive.

- the time from each person.
- the time of each person.

Comment: "I want the total time", "I want the sum of everyone's time"

Comment: Don't you think your Question would be better answered somewhere like English Language Users SE?

Answer (score 2):

`every people's time` is wrong, you cannot (most of the time) use a plural noun with `every`. `All people's time` is not a correct choice either. Luckily, there's a single word to describe this: `everyone`:

```
I want to sum everyone's time
```

That one is correct, but you may want consider the following alternative:

```
I want the total time
```